Example request: Local algebra with exactly two indecomposable modules
I'm looking for non-trivial examples of finite dimensional local algebras with exactly two indecomposable modules. So far, I've only found $k[x]/ \langle x^2 \rangle$ and $k$ for a field $k$.
Any help will be extremely appreciated! <3

Not sure if this helps. Let $R$ be a finite dimensional local $K$-algebra with maximal ideal $J$ and exactly two indecomposable modules. Then $J\neq 0$ and $R$ and $R/J$ are these two (non-isomorphic) modules.
I'm going to show $J^2=0$. As $J/J^2$ is semisimple, there exists a simple direct summand $E/J^2$ of $J/J^2$ and a decomposition $J/J^2 = E/J^2 \oplus D/J^2$, for some $J^2\subseteq D\subset J$. Then $R/D$ is an indecomposable, non-simple module with simple radical $J/D \simeq E/J^2$. Hence $R\simeq R/D$. Comparing the dimension we have $D=J^2=0$.
For an example, take a field $K$ and a field automorphism $\sigma\in \mathrm{Aut}(K)$ of order $2$, i.e. $\sigma^2 = id_K$. Form the skewpolynomial ring $K[x,\sigma]$ which consists of (left) polynomials $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ with $a_i \in K$ such that $$xa = \sigma(a)x, \qquad \forall a\in K.$$
Since $\sigma$ has order $2$, $x^2$ is a central element and the $K$-algebra $R=K[x;\sigma]/\langle x^2\rangle$ is a two-dimensional non-commutative local ring with unique maximal ideal $J=R\overline{x}=\overline{x}R$. For any element of the form $a+b\overline{x}$ with $a\neq 0$, its inverse is $a^{-1}(1-b\sigma(a^{-1})\overline{x})$.
Concretely, you might take $K=\mathbb{C}$ and for $\sigma$ complex conjugation.

Yes, this is helpful. Thank you very much!
